# Jquery - Trap All Form Submissions

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

On my site I have multiple pages containing forms. Each form has it's own unique name.

Some forms are submitted using a standard HTML submit button, some using jquery and others using a simple JavaScript function, like :

```
function form()
    {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }

onchange="form()"
```

What I'd like to do is record anytime a form is submitted. I'm happy to output this to the console.log, once I have that working..

I'll look to send the data to a new page via Ajax and then write it to disk.

Can anyone suggest how this could be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try overwritting DOM node `submit()` method and binding jQuery `submit` event at `document` level, e.g:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function () {
    $(this).submit(); // trigger jq submit handler
}

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(this, data);
    // call any ajax method to submit data
    // >>>>
});
```

**EDIT:** 
If you want to keep default behaviour of submitting the `form`, you could use:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function () {
    $(this).submit(); // trigger jq submit handler
}

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(this, data);
    this._submit(); // call default prototype 'submit' method
    // or call it from any ajax callback method e.g 'success'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but I want to capture all the output to the console.log / or to disk and have the form submit as normal ! is that possible ?

Comment: @JeffVader Updated answer. See if it fits your needs?!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - Thanks I'll try this today. Can you advise what this does : `HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function () {
    $(this).submit(); // trigger jq submit handler
}`

I can understand the rest :D  Thanks